# what is the difference between L-system and string re-writing?

Tags: chomsky-hierarchy

I was going through the L-System Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) and it mentions that L-Systems are very similar to unrestricted grammars / string re-writing. After going through the Wikipedia, I can't see any difference between the two? does anyone know what they might be?

Comment: Parallellism. Ordinary string rewriting applies one rule at a time at one position in the string. In L systems rules are used to rewrite all symbols in the  string at the same time.